# RENAME function not renaming in batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename, file-rename

EDIT: I have updated this post to include the entire script.

EDIT: While not ideal, this is meant to be an automation of a fix provided by the company that makes the software.

I have a batch file that I am running as Administrator.

I am running a batch file based on the file system input by the user.

One of the first commands renames a file.

If I execute this command on its own, from an elevated command prompt, it renames the file.

When I nest the command inside the IF statement, it doesn't rename the file.

I have commented out all of the other lines to simply rename the file if the user enters "1".

I have tried encapsulating the file path and file each individually within quotes, which I shouldn't need, and still do not get it to rename the file.

I am running the batch script as Admin.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%$ecbId%" == "" (
    echo Welcome to the ADaPT 
    echo Choose '1' for 32 bit
    echo Choose '2' for 64 bit
    echo Type anything else to abort.
    echo.
    set "UserChoice=abort"
    set /P "UserChoice=Type your choice: "
    if "!UserChoice!"=="1" (
        echo Executing 32 bit sequence...       
        echo Regsvr32.exe /u C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        echo REN C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX MSCOMCTL.bak
        xcopy C:\install\MSCOMCTL.OCX C:\Windows\System32 folder
        Regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        Regsvr32.exe /u C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        del "C:\Windows\System32\ MSCOMCTL.OCX"
        echo REN "C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.bak" "MSCOMCTL.OCX"
        Recho Regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        shutdown.exe /r /t 00
    )

    if "!UserChoice!"=="2" (
        echo Regsvr32.exe /u C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        echo REN "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX" "MSCOMCTL.bak"
        xcopy C:\install\MSCOMCTL.OCX C:\Windows\SYSWOW64 folder
        Regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        Regsvr32.exe /u C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        del "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\ MSCOMCTL.OCX"
        echo REN "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.bak" "MSCOMCTL.OCX"
        echo Regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
        REM... shutdown.exe /r /t 00
    )
    if not "!UserChoice!"=="1" (
        echo toto3
        if not "!UserChoice!"=="2" (
            echo toto4
            echo Unknown input ... Aborting script
            endlocal
            exit /B 400
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Do you have delayed expansion enabled higher up in your script? Your script will only echo that it is renaming the file.  If you want to rename it, you must remove the echo.

Comment: Yes it does I have updated it.

Comment: ....also your parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: I really hope that this batch file never works or at least is never executed on one of my Windows computers. I would not be happy on corruption of my Windows machines by replacing *Windows Common Controls ActiveX Control DLL* by this method. I really hope that Windows file system redirector, Windows file protection,  and Windows side-by-side prevents an exchange of such an important system DLL by a method like that. Fortunately this important system DLL is always loaded on Windows running and so it can't be renamed or deleted by a batch file like the posted one.

Comment: @Magoo, I did not enter the entire script, only the offending IF block.

Comment: @MarkSaluta, you have been on StackOverFlow long enough to know how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Squashman, I am perfectly willing to accept that. Thanks.

Comment: As I stated in my first comment, all you have is a bunch of echo commands. None of your code actually does a rename.

Comment: @Mofi, We have a third party application that requires us to execute this series of steps whenever the application fails to load certain components. It is the only published fix, and we currently do this manually. You mention that you would not be happy with this method, is there another method that I could try?

Comment: @Squashman, Hey so you did :-). That comment was much appreciated. I've been spending more time on StackOverflow than on my batch file since having been given some tips and advice. I haven't been as active as I used to be, and my return has been in less than good form. I will work on the script with the tips given, though Mofi's comment has me somewhat concerned that I might be better off utilizing a different method.

Comment: Given that you've now posted the entire script, I have to say that it is absolutely crazy to structure it whereby `%$ecbId%` hasn't been defined and the entire script is effectively and unnecessarily placed within an `If` parenthesized block.

Comment: @Compo, I would certainly use a heavy handicap in Codegolf. Really it is just a lack of experience on my part. In my mind, I think "I am doing this manually." I then look up how to do that same thing programmatically. I do the rest of that with the remaining steps, and then arrange them in the sequential order they originally were in. I added the logic, because there are two different file systems. I'm open to learning though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your entire script structure so as not to require parenthesised blocks, *or the need to delay expansion*:

```bat
@Echo Off

If Defined $ecbId GoTo :EOF

Echo Welcome to the ADaPT

Choice /C CQ /M "Continue or Quit"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :EOF

Set "Dest=TEM32"
Set PROCESSOR_ARCHITE|Find "64">Nul&&(Set Dest=WOW64)
Set "Dest=%SYSTEMROOT%\SYS%Dest%"

Echo Executing sequence . . .

RegSvr32 /U "%Dest%\MSCOMCTL.OCX"

Rem To backup and replace MSCOMCTL.OCX:
Rem  Uncomment the next three unRemarked lines
Rem   and comment the next three unRemarked lines below them.
::Del /A /F "MSCOMCTL.bak" 2>Nul
::Ren "%Dest%\MSCOMCTL.OCX" "MSCOMCTL.bak"
::XCopy "C:\install\MSCOMCTL.OCX" "%Dest%"
Rem To recover MSCOMCTL.OCX from the backup:
Rem  Comment the next three unRemarked lines
Rem   and uncomment the previous three unRemarked lines above them.
If Not Exist "MSCOMCTL.bak" RegSvr32 "%Dest%\MSCOMCTL.OCX" & GoTo :EOF
Del /A /F "%Dest%\MSCOMCTL.OCX"
Ren "%Dest%\MSCOMCTL.bak" "MSCOMCTL.OCX"

RegSvr32 "%Dest%\MSCOMCTL.OCX"
ShutDown /R /T 0 /D P:2:4
```

**Notes:**
It is probably safe to delete lines `3` and empty line `4`, *I left them in only because no explanation was provided as to the purpose of the `%$ecbId%` variable value comparison*.
I have added `Rem`arks for toggling the script for the backup or recovery methods, but not knowingly altered any of your command sequence, *(I have however added the `/A` and `/F` options with `Del`, just in case, and included the `/D` option with `ShutDown` to ensure that the logs show it as a planned shutdown event)*.